# Which type/class should I use to map different values?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a backend table as shown below and I am reading it using ado.net.

I tried to convert this to a dictionary with key value pair, but I don't know how to map keys and values so that when I read `code 1` I can return its category name, and when I read 2 as `code 3` as subcode I can read both its corresponding category and subcategory?(Say ex., Old, ThreeMonth).

Is there any other type/class available to acheive this functionality?

```
code    Sub_Code    Category    Sub_Category
1             1     NEW                  NEW
2             1         Old             OneMonth
2             2         Old                 TwoMonth
2             3         Old                 ThreeMonth
2             4         Old                 Ninemonth
5             4     APPOINTMENT         APPOINTMENT MADE
9             4         Invalid             LANGUAGE BARRIER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options, depending on what operations you need to do with the data, how often it changes, etc. Some obvious ones are:

### Nested Types

Create a custom type to hold your category and its sub-categories. This has the benefit that you can skip the sub-categories if there are none, and your data type can exactly map to your business object.

```
public class Category 
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  Dictionary<int, string> Subcategories = new Dictionary<int, string>();
}

Dictionary<int, Category> Categories;
```

(I'd also consider a `KeyedCollection` here that can extract the `Id` from a `Category` as the key directly.)

The downside: its a bit more work to add or retrieve a subcategory because you have to do two lookups:

```
var subcategory = Categories[1].Subcategories[1];
```

### A 4-Tuple (quadruple?)

If your data structure rarely changes you can use a 4-field `Tuple<>`:

```
List<Tuple<int, int, string, string>> Categories;
var subcategory = Categories.Where(x => Item1 == 1 && Item2 == 1);
```

The biggest downside here is that it's not indexed very well. You could alleviate that a bit, at the cost of even more complexity, by using two `Tuples` (one key, one value):

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tuple<string, string>> Categories;
```

But IMO that gets kinda messy, and at that point I'd just go with a custom class.

### Split Collections

Split up the category name and subcategories into separate collections: one holds the cateogory id -> name mapping, and the other holds the category id -> subcategory mapping:

```
Dictionary<id, string> CategoryNames;
Dictionary<id, Dictionary<id, string>> Subcatgories;
```

This is more flexible than the `Tuple` solution but doesn't involve a custom data type, so it's a more "quick and dirty" solution. Also, if you commonly find yourself *only* caring about one or the other, having the data separate may make things more efficient.

Comment: My personal opinion, BTW: I'd definitely go with a `KeyedCollection` of custom `Category` classes over any of the other options.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I too mentioned in my question itself as i want to go for custom one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary also as the value of the main dictionary. So you would access your data using 
    dict[category][sub]

Another option is to use Tuple as they key which "codes" both the main key, and the secondary key into a single unique key